# I need to update the changes made to the text file constantly and display in the browser without refreshing

Tags: node.js

I can display the file contents in the browser and update the changes with reloading. I need to update the changes in the text file in the browser without reloading it every time.

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');
var filepath="C:/Projects/Test/doc.txt";
var server = http.createServer(function (req, resp) {
     if (req.url === "/read") {
      fs.readFile("C:/Projects/Test/doc.txt", function (error, pgResp) {
        if (error) {
            resp.writeHead(404);
            resp.write('Contents you are looking are Not Found');
        } 
           else {
            var file=fs.readFileSync(filepath);
            fs.watchFile(filepath,function(){
                console.log("file changed");
                file=fs.readFileSync(filepath);
            resp.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/html' });
                    });
        }
          resp.end(file);
    });
} 
});
server.listen(5050);
console.log('Server Started listening on 5050');
```

Comment: Reloading means? The server? And did you try anything to achieve this so far? Can we have a look at them if you have any?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Socket](https://socket.io/) to maintain continuous data transfer between server and client. It's very easy to start with.

However, if your goal is only to achieve this specific API in your app and no other feature related to Socket then you can implement firing APIs at some time interval which keeps checking the file content.